# How to render a component along with changing url in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have Manage Items page where can see items in a table with two actions as `Edit` and `Delete`.

Required, on click of edit/delete button the Edit/Delete component should be rendered with url like `manage-items/edit/1` or `manage-items/edit?id=1`

Currently:

- Base URL: `manage-items`

Required:

- Edit URL: `manage-items/edit/1` or `manage-items/edit?id=1`
- Delete URL: `manage-items/delete/1` or `manage-items/delete?id=1`

Tried below code.

```js
const ManageItems = () => {
...
    return (
        <div>
            {edit ? <Routes> <Route path="/edit/:itemId" element={<EditItem itemId={itemId}/>} /> </Routes>
            : delete ? <Routes> <Route path="/delete/:itemId" element={<DeleteItem itemId={itemId}/>} /> </Routes>
            : <ItemTable items={items}/>}
        </div>
    );
};
```

When both the flags `edit` and `delete` are false then I am able to see item table but on click none of the other components Edit or Delete is rendering, nor the URL is changing.
Its just empty white space there.

If I remove  and  then can see both Edit and Delete components accordingly but no effect on the URL.

**Nee to change the URL accordingly on click.**

Other code:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div id="App" className="app-wrapper">
      <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
          <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
            <Routes>
              {/* public routes */}
              <Route path={PORTAL_PATH_BASE} element={<Login />} />
              <Route
                path={PORTAL_PATH_UNAUTHORIZED}
                element={<ErrorFallback error={COMMON_ERRORS.unauthorized} />}
              />
              <Route
                path={PORTAL_PATH_PAGENOTFOUND}
                element={<ErrorFallback error={COMMON_ERRORS.pageNotFound} />}
              />
              <Route
                path={PORTAL_PATH_LOGINCALLBACK}
                element={<LoginCallback />}
              />
              {/* we want to protect these routes */}
              <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
                <Route
                  path={`${PORTAL_PATH_BASE}/*`}
                  element={
                    <WithAxios>
                      <MyAdmin />
                    </WithAxios>
                  }
                />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </ErrorBoundary>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


const MyAdmin = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [headerNavItems, setHeaderNavItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let headerMenuCodes =
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEYS.UserInfo)).menu.map(
        (m) => m.menuCode
      ) || [];
    setHeaderNavItems(
      NAV_ITEM_LIST.filter(
        (hdr) => headerMenuCodes.includes(hdr.key) || hdr.key === "XY"
      )
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomHeader navItemList={headerNavItems} />
      <PageBanner
        Title={
          MANAGE_ROUTES.find((route) => route.path === pathname)
            ?.title
        }
      >
        <CustomBreadcrumb />
      </PageBanner>
      <ScrollToTop>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={PORTAL_SUB_PATH_HOME} element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path={`${PORTAL_SUB_PATH_BPR}/*`}
            element={<BuildingProgress />}
          />
          <Route path={`${PORTAL_SUB_PATH_MANAGE}/*`} element={<ManageItems />} />
          <Route path={`${PORTAL_SUB_PATH_RPT}/*`} element={<Settings />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </ScrollToTop>
    </div>
  );
};

const DeleteItem = ({itemId}) => {
    ... load item in readonly fields and allow to confirm delete ...
}

const ItemTable = ({items, onEdit, onDelete}) => {
    ... Show table of items with two action buttons as Edit and Delete ...
}

const EditItem = ({itemId}) => {
    ... load item in editable fields and allow to save change ...
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong here?

Comment: I think you are defining routes again in the manage item component. It should render the component directly like. {edit ? <EditItem itemId={itemId}/> : delete ? <DeleteItem itemId={itemId}/> : <ItemTable items={items}/>}

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your routes in the root App/index component.
Something like this.

```
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App Header</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/manage-items">
          <Route index element={<ManageItems />} />
          <Route path="edit/:id" element={<h2>Edit</h2>} />
          <Route path="delete/:id" element={<h2>Delete</h2>} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<h2>Not Found</h2>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <Link to="/manage-items">Go to Items</Link>
    </>
  );
};

const ManageItems = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Manage Items</h1>
      <div>
        <Link to="edit/1">Edit</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="delete/1">Delete</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Sample code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-bash-hcvukk

Comment: Getting page not found.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what `edit`, `delete`, and `itemId` are in the `ManageItems` component, but I suspect these are entirely unnecessary, just render the content on unconditional routes and let `react-router-dom` do it's "thing" and render the best match. The issue that happens when you conditionally render routes is that the state they depend on hasn't been updated by React and the component rerendered ***prior*** to the navigation action is processed that navigates to the route path. In other words, the route isn't mounted to navigate to.

I also suspect that you really want `EditItem` and `DeleteItem` to get the `itemId` value from the route path param and ***not*** as a passed prop.

This assumes you've some UI logic somewhere that is navigating between these sub-routes to switch between the edit/delete and the base index routes, e.g. the different "display modes".

Example:

```
const ManageItems = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          // "/{PORTAL_PATH_BASE}/{PORTAL_SUB_PATH_MANAGE}/edit/:itemId"
          path="/edit/:itemId"
          element={<EditItem />}
        />
        <Route
          // "/{PORTAL_PATH_BASE}/{PORTAL_SUB_PATH_MANAGE}/delete/:itemId"
          path="/delete/:itemId"
          element={<DeleteItem />}
        />
        <Route
          // "/{PORTAL_PATH_BASE}/{PORTAL_SUB_PATH_MANAGE}"
          index
          element={<ItemTable items={items} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const EditItem = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();

  ...
};
```

```
const DeleteItem = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew, 
Currently, `edit` and `delete` are the flags based on which we are switching the component to render between `EditItems`, `DeleteItems` (takes `itemId`) and `ItemTable` in the section of the manage page itself. Not Route based approach hence no change in URL.

Comment: @Prem So is the router and routes irrelevant here? Sorry if I've somehow completely misunderstood your post. Can you clarify your comment?

Comment: Getting `Page Not Found`
Even tried ```<Routes>
 <Route
   path="/edit"
   element={<h2>Edit page</h2>}
 />
 <Route
   path="/delete"
   element={<h2>Delete page</h2>}
 />
 <Route
   index
   element={<h2>Manage</h2>}
 />
</Routes>```
And hit `.../manage-items/edit` and `.../manage-items/delete`.
Could be some code in `App` or `MyAdmin` is blocking my `/edit` and `/delete` for `manage`?
Could you please have look on `App` and `MyAdmin`.
Thanks!

Comment: In existing there is not Route but now trying to switch to Route approach so that URL like `.../manage-items/edit/1` is used.

Comment: @Prem I suppose it depends on what all these route patch enum values are. Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve]? Can you also try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?